# Are segments painted randomly respective to previously painted segments?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I have a sequence of $N$ binary values (`+` and `-`). At $t=0$, all values are minuses (`-`)

```
t=0: ----------------------------
```

Over time, segments of various sizes of this sequence get set to `+`. I am then, talking of a "painted segment". Note that never a value get set back to `-` (impossible to remove the paint). The dynamic might look like:

```
t=0:  ----------------------------
t=1:  ----------------------------
t=2:  ----------------------------
t=3:  ----------------------------
t=4:  -------------------++++-----
t=5:  -------------------++++-----
t=6:  --+++--------------++++-----
t=7:  --+++--------------++++-----
t=8:  --+++--------------++++-----
t=9:  --+++--------------++++-----
t=10: --+++-++-----------++++-----
t=11: --+++-++-----++++++++++-----
t=12: --+++-++-----++++++++++-----
t=13: --+++-++-----++++++++++-----
t=14: --+++-++-----++++++++++-----
t=15: --+++-++-----++++++++++-----
t=16: --+++-++-----++++++++++--+++
t=17: --+++-++-----++++++++++--+++
t=18: --++++++-----++++++++++--+++
t=19: --++++++-----++++++++++--+++
t=20: --++++++-----+++++++++++++++
t=21: --++++++-----+++++++++++++++
t=22: --+++++++++--+++++++++++++++
t=23: --+++++++++--+++++++++++++++
t=24: +-+++++++++--+++++++++++++++
```

I would like to figure whether the painted segments happen at random among the sequences "unpainted" or whether they tend to be clustered or whether they tend to be spread. In short, my question is "Are segments painted randomly respective to previously painted segments?"

Note that the concept of repainting an already painted segment is meaningless.

Here is an example where the painted segments are clustered

```
t=0:  ----------------------------
t=1:  ----------------------------
t=2:  -------------------++++-----
t=3:  -------------------++++-----
t=4:  ---------------++++++++-----
t=5:  ---------------++++++++-----
t=6:  ----------+++--++++++++-----
t=7:  ----------+++++++++++++-----
t=8:  ----------+++++++++++++-----
t=9:  ----------+++++++++++++-----
t=10: ----------++++++++++++++++--
t=11: ------++--++++++++++++++++--
t=12: ------++--++++++++++++++++--
t=13: ------++++++++++++++++++++--
t=14: ------++++++++++++++++++++++
```

and here is an example, where the painted segments are spread

```
t=0:  ----------------------------
t=1:  ----------------------------
t=2:  -------------------++++-----
t=3:  -------------------++++-----
t=4:  ++-----------------++++-----
t=5:  ++-----------------++++-----
t=6:  ++------+++--------++++-----
t=7:  ++------+++--------++++-----
t=8:  ++------+++--------++++-----
t=9:  ++------+++--------++++---++
t=10: ++------+++--------++++---++
t=11: ++------+++--------++++---++
t=12: ++------+++-+++----++++---++
t=13: ++------+++-+++----++++---++
t=14: ++------+++-+++----++++---++
t=15: ++-+++--+++-+++----++++---++
t=16: ++-+++--+++-+++----++++---++
t=17: ++-+++--+++-+++--++++++---++
```

How can I investigate that? What null distribution(s) I could use for hypothesis(ese) testing? Do I need data over time or is a single screenshot at $t=\tau$ enough?

It does not matter much but for my specific case, $N$ is of the order of 100 millions and the largest $t$ value if of the order of 1000. I do not necessarily have access to $t$ values where the entire sequence is set to `+`.

Comment: You can simply apply one of a great many available randomness tests (for permutations) to the sequence of painted segments.  However, if you have some theories about the ways in which the sequence might be non-random (such as a tendency to choose locations close to already-painted segments) then that could be used to devise a test that is more powerful than any off-the-shelf omnibus randomness test.

Comment: I personally expect that a segment close by a painted segment is more likely to get paint soon. By it is a vague intuition and some collaborators of mine expect otherwise. In short, we are far to come up with a model for this process. You mentioned omnibus test. Could you explain how an F-test, ANOVA, Chi-squared test and others could help here? Yes, a permutation would be a good idea. Maybe using "distance to closest painted segment" as statistic of interest. I can only imagine how such permutation test could be used with a single screenshort but that would be fine.

Comment: I meant "omnibus" in its standard English sense: there are entire suites of tests of random number generators and they include permutation tests.  See Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* for an extensive account.